# When I delete a folder or a file in Django manually and try to run the project I'm getting error on the same module which I have deleted?

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, web-development-server

I have deleted a folder named accounts from my Django project and tried to run the file, but getting this error

> "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'accounts'"

Even though I have deleted manually, it's asking me to delete the paths as well. How to get over from this error?

Answer (score 0):

How DjangoStarter said, check your installed apps and the imports in other apps.